# Absolute URL on localhost and web server for YII Framework?

Tags: php, url, yii, yii2, localhost

I am using YII2 framework in netbeans, every time my project is deployed to the web server I have to change the url to that of the web server from localhost.
Therefore, 
 
Created a config.php file in the controller folder

> define("LOCAL", "http://localhost"); 
>    define("WEB", "http://website.com"); 
>    global $environment; 
>    $environment= LOCAL; //change to WEB if you're live

Every file that needs it, put this at the top

> include_once(dirname( __FILE __)."/config.php");

and every time the url is needed in the code call it using

> echo $environment;

But I get the error that $environment is not defined.
What am I doing wrong?

Reference [How to implement absolute URLs on localhost and web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371599/how-to-implement-absolute-urls-on-localhost-and-web-server)

Comment: I think config.php file is not included in project. check any error is displaying or just change the `include_once; ` to `required_once` so that if it is not include, remaining line of code will not run and we can find whether it is included or not.

Answer (score 1):

Create db_config.php file in you config folder like below -

```
define('DB_NAME', '');

define('DB_USER', 'root');

define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

after that - if you want to access that global variables then user like this -
create new function for connection in your controller

```
private function connectToDb($db_name) {
    include Yii::getAlias('@app') . "/config/db_config.php"; // Include db_config.php file
    $connection = new \yii\db\Connection([
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . $db_name,
        'username' => DB_USER,
        'password' => DB_PASSWORD,
    ]);
    return $connection;
}
```

After that call above function from anywhere from controller like below -

```
$super_conn = $this->connectToDb('my_db_name');
$super_conn->open();
$sql = "select * form student where id = 1"; //your query 
$super_conn->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

thank you..
hope this will help...